# DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL Message is sending unrecognisable Class GUIDs

Tags: c++, winapi, ports

I am attempting to determine the Class Type of a device that has been connected to the computer. If its a Monitor(for eg a TV or Projector) I want to perform specific actions like change the display settings of the computer.

My method of determining the class type of a device involves the following steps:

> - Register for device notifications
> - Detect WM_DEVICECHANGE events: if the wParam value = DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
>
>   - I convert the lParam value to a PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE variable and inspect that variables
>       dbcc_classguid attribute
>   - If the dbcc_classguid attribute == "{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}" then I have found a monitor device

**My Problem:** Whenever I connect my LG Wide Screen TV to my computer it sends an unrecognisable dbcc_classguid.

For some reason, upon connection of the TV I receive 2 DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL messages. The lParam contains the following GUID's. What kind of [device class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426) is this?:

> {e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}
>   {866519b5-3f07-4c97-b7df-24c5d8a8ccb8}

Funnily enough if I inspect the Windows Device Manager application(after I have connected the TV) I can see that the TV is stored under Monitors and that its class GUID is indeed the Monitor Class GUID, ie, {4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}. So this is REALLY weird. Also I connected a regular computer monitor screen to my laptop and it sent the exact same GUIDs and also sent 2 arrival messages.

Heres my code. Why am I receiving weird Class GUIDs upon connection of a TV to my computer? What kind of device are those 2 GUID's for? Maybe I am receiving the *Hardware GUIDs* and not the *Class GUIDs*?

```
    case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
    {
        PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR pBroad = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR) lParam;
        if (pBroad->dbch_devicetype != DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE) {
            debug_print("pBroad->dbch_devicetype != DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE\n");
            break;
        }

        PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE pInter = (PDEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE) pBroad;
        _tprintf(_T("Device Data: %s\n %x\n\n"), pInter->dbcc_name, pInter->dbcc_devicetype);

        debug_print("Printing Device Data");
        outputDeviceData(toString(pInter->dbcc_classguid), SPDRP_CLASSGUID);

        if (isMonitorDevice(pInter->dbcc_classguid)) {
            // TODO: change display mode and etc.
            debug_print("is MonitorDevice!!!");
        }
        else debug_print("is NOT MonitorDevice!!!");
    }
    break;
```

The output of my application is:

> Message DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
>
> Device Data:
>   \?\DISPLAY#GSM3AD7#5&20a3f50d&0&UID513#{866519b5-3f07-4c97-b7df-24
>   c5d8a8ccb8}  5
>
> {866519b5-3f07-4c97-b7df-24c5d8a8ccb8} is NOT MonitorDevice!!!
>
> Message DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
>
> Device Data:
>   \?\DISPLAY#GSM3AD7#5&20a3f50d&0&UID513#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33
>   f57bf4eaa7}  5
>
> {e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7} is NOT MonitorDevice!!!

Answer (score 1):

`{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}` is `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR`

MSDN page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Something must be wrong with your `isMonitorDevice()` function, I can't see it from here.  Use IsEqualGUID() to compare guid values.

Comment: any idea what {866519b5-3f07-4c97-b7df-24c5d8a8ccb8} is?

Comment: Look in the registry, HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses key.